# NOOBS recovery password

Tags: kernel, password

I have installed a new kernel, but for some reason, it won't boot. I generated the `kernel.img` with `imagetool-uncompressed.py`, but now my Raspberry Pi fails to boot. I have made a backup of the old `kernel.img`, and want to restore it. I need to know the NOOBS `root` password (you can access a terminal with ctrl-alt-f2) to restore it.

Comment: in the arch linux build, the root password is root, but you shouldn't have to know it, why can't you just use [sudo](http://wiki.debian.org/sudo)?

Comment: I am at NOOBS, and I push ctrl-alt-f2 to get to a login screen, from there, what is the password for `root`?

Comment: if you want to restore the old kernel, all you have to do is put the SD card back into your computer and mount the /boot partition (it should mount automatically). From there just replace your corrupted kernel with the backup one.

Comment: @John I don't have an SD card reader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/9127ef2ce9301c3c8bf91b5c2ef09af90bf00216/buildroot/.config

User:pass = root:raspberry

Answer (score 0):

For the Rescue System:
User = root
Password = raspberry

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your answer makes me wonder, what does it provide that the existing one does not? Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.